# Notification when a new image is added to camera folder of Android mobile

Tags: android, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I am using Xamarin and MvvmCross for my Android mobile app. I want to have some sort of notification as soon as a new photo is saved in the camera folder.

Is there any event handler/ notification when new file is added to camera folder?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Android.OS.FileObserver,** you only need to implement the **OnEvent()** and one(+) Constructors.
Notes:

- Watch on a path, if you need to filter by file, do it in the OnEvent
- Do not let your FileObserver object get GC'd or your OnEvents will
  stop woking.
- Remember to call StartWatching() in order to receive OnEvent calls